# Import Excel with numbers with decimals Laravel 5.3

Tags: excel, database, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to import an Excel like this...
[my excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPmVP.png)

and in my code, I have this...

```
   \Excel::load($request->excel, function($reader) {

    $excel = $reader->get();

    // iteracción
    $reader->each(function($row) {
        $time = strtotime($row->date);
        $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);

        $registry=Registry::create([
            'description' => $row->description,
            'quantity' => $row->quantity,
            'price' => $row->price,
            'date' => $newformat,
        ]);
        $registry->save();

    });

});

return "Ok!";
```

In my DB everything is ok. Except the price column.

It is always in 0.

any ideas? Ty!

Comment: What's your `price` column type?

Comment: In my migration I declare it as float.